# magento 2 - Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, package, key

Trying to install magento 2 on localhost. I am getting this message

> Invalid credentials for 'repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.

Initially, I had created a secure key by navigating to magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customerdata/secureKeys/list/ url.

I tried `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>` command and entered the username as public key and password as private key. I was then prompted whether I need to save it? And I selected the option "Y".

But by some mistake the secure key  got deleted.

Now, when I am trying to create a new project, its giving me

> Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.

I want to update my `auth.json` file . But I'm unable to get the command. Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use your **public key as username** and **private key as password** from your magento connect account

you can find the public and private key at:

https://developer.magento.com/customer/account/

> Developer Portal -> My Access Keys -> Create A New Access Key(Or using exsting key)

Comment: works, magento is weird

Comment: Is it working on localhost upgrade?

Comment: @Gem yes its working! and perfect answer! made my day! +1

Comment: @Prince i have same issue but not working for me (http://prntscr.com/mzww21)

Comment: @RakeshDonga Are you trying with `Create A New Access Key` ?

Comment: yes but still same issue facing i have also create auth.json file

Comment: how to create a auth.json file @RakeshDonga

Comment: You should create a developer account first. If you have already login to it and go to https://developer.magento.com/account/keys  and create Access Keys You will get two key one Public one Private Public you can use as Username and Private as password in CLI to authenticate.